# htaccess параметры в цикле

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Можно ли реализовать подобное проще? Если необходимо до param20

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ ?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3&param4=$4&param5=$5&param6=$6 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Лучше свой скрипт научите разгребать эту строку. если это php - то explode('/') даст вам отличный массив параметров

Comment: Нельзя. ради безопасности

Comment: Хм. странная безопасность. У скрипта обычно гораздо больше возможностей по проверки корректности переданных параметров

Comment: И если не ошибаюсь 20 параметров вы не сможете обработать. Максимум там 10 шт.